AddClass no funciona en todos los registros de mi datatable
tengo un problema tengo una vista con una datatable que lista 10 filas por página, el problema lo tengo cuando agrego una clase para una función en uno de los botones, esto funciona perfecto en los 10 primeros registros que se listan pero cuadno voy a la segunda página esos botones no toman la clase.
El elemento en cuestión es el botón amarillo

Cuando paso a la 2da página el botón no toma la clase... se mantiene en su clase base. he leído algo del DOM pero no tengo idea de como considerarlo en este caso.

en mi sección de script tengo esto
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
        });

        $("a.btn-info").addClass('btn-warning').attr("title","Extender Facturacion").html('<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></>');
        $("a.btn-info").click(function(){
            let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $("input[name='id']").val(id);
            $("#modal-extend").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard:false},'show');
            return false;
        });

en el body donde está la tabla tengo esto:
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-success">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2><i class="fas fa-star"></i> {{ $title }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                @include('admin.partials.table',['columns'=>$columns, 'data'=>$data, 'route'=>'subscriptions'])
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

y en la vista partials.table tengo esto:
    <div class="card-body table-responsive"> 
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sm display compact table-bordered not-desktop">
    <thead>
        @foreach($columns as $col)
            <th>{{$col['title']}}</th>
        @endforeach
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $d)
            <tr>
                @foreach($columns as $col)
                @php
                    $key = $col['key'];
                    $type = "text";
                    if(array_key_exists("type", $col)){
                        $type = $col['type'];
                    }
                @endphp
                  <td>
                    @switch($type)
                        @case('text')
                            @if($d->$key)
                                {{$d->$key}}
                            @else
                                -
                            @endif
                        @break

                        @case('currency')
                            {{$col['data']['symbol']}} {{number_format($d->$key,2,',','.')}}
                        @break

                        @case('img')
                            @if(!empty($d->$key))
                                <img src="{{ asset(str_replace('public','storage',$d->$key)) }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:100px; height: 100px;" alt="image">
                            @else
                                Sin Imagen
                            @endif
                        @break

                        @case('replace_text')
                            {{$col['data'][$d->$key]}}
                        @break

                        @case('relation')
                            @php
                                $format = "plain";
                                $relation = $col['data']['relation'];
                                $key = $col['data']['key'];
                                if(array_key_exists("format",$col['data'])){
                                    $format = $col['data']['format'];
                                }
                            @endphp

                            @if(@$format == 'plain')
                                {{$d->$relation->$key}}
                            @else
                                {!!@$d->$relation->$key!!}
                            @endif

                        @break

                        @case('date')
                            @if(!empty($d->$key))
                                {{ date($col['data']['format'], strtotime($d->$key)) }}
                            @else
                                -
                            @endif
                        @break

                        @case('html')
                            {!!$d->$key!!}
                        @break
                    @endswitch
                  </td>
                @endforeach
                <td>
                    @include('admin.partials.actions',[ 'route'=>$route, 'id' => $d->id ])
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

y en la vista partials.actions tengo esto:
    <a href="{{ route($route.'.edit', $id) }}" data-id='{{$id}}' class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
<form style="display:inline;" method="POST" action="{{ route($route.'.destroy', $id) }}" id="form_{{$id}}">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-record" data-id="{{$id}}"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
</form>

Les agradezco la colaboración que puedan prestarme

No entiendo porque querés cambiar el boton con JS, podés hacerlo directo en partials.action
en vez de
 class="btn btn-sm btn-info"

poner
class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"

Si no querés hacerlo asi, podes cambiar la clase "btn-info" para que se vea con el estilo que quieras.
Si aun asi querés usar javascript, solo te funciona en la primera pagina porque solo se ejecuta cuando se carga todo el dom la primera vez. Tenes que usar un evento de datatables para que se ejecute cada vez que se dibuja la tabla.
Creo yo que el evento seria "draw", pero no lo he probado => https://datatables.net/manual/events

Ok lo que sucede es que no solo cambia la clase sino que se ejecuta un función en esa vista específicamente, prácticamente se disfraza la función base del botón y en esa vista genera una función con un modal.
